# Jquery Tab menu scroll arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am new learner to jquery/js. I am having difficulties making a scroll tab menu. Here my example tabs in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/apRrq/14/). My goal is to only display 5 tabs and hide the rest tabs. So if the user wants to see the hidden tabs they will click on the side arrows. Is there are bettter way to do this or Can anyone please show me how this mechanism work with my example?

[image: Scroll Tab Menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous plugins available for this:

Here's one example

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/LtmA5/1/

Source:

http://jquery.aamirafridi.com/jst/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am starting to figure this out